# Programmatically controlling a carousel in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, carousel, kivy

I'm new with kivy, but I have decent experience with Python and Tkinter. I'm trying to control a carousel in kivy programmatically. Essentially, I have an external python program which I want to use to automatically switch images in the carousel. To make an example, I have some code in another file:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    #do something to control the carousel
```

and then I have my kivy app:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

class CarouselApp(App):
    self.srcs = ["/a/bunch.png", "/of/paths.jpg", "/to/images.png."]

    def build(self):
        self.carousel = Carousel(direction="right")
        for i in range(0, len(self.srcs)):
            src = self.srcs[i]
            image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            self.carousel.add_widget(image)
        return self.carousel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CarouselApp().run()
```

I would like to be able to control which slide is displayed in the carousel using the top code, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that, since I can't execute anything after `App.run()`
I have investigated kivy's `Clock` module, but I'm not sure that would work for me since I want to switch slides when certain conditions are satisfied rather than on a time basis. The time example I gave is simply an example of my line of thinking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you wanna add a source to each element of the carousel?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The sources of the image files are all known prior to the carousel being initialized, technically. What I'm aiming to do is after the carouselapp has been created, and after an external condition is satisfied in the above code, I would like to switch slides in the carousel. I basically want to run `Carousel.load_next()` but I want to do it from outside of the carousel app.

Comment: I have provided an answer, and I hope this helps. In the end, you have to schedule a function in the `on_start` method and then control your carousel on that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest using a Kivy file to handle this situation. Second, `AsyncImage` is used when you want to use an image that will be downloaded from the Internet, and as I can see you have the images you are going to use are locally stored, so use `Image` instead.

I think you should implement the method `on_start` in the class which is extending `App` (`CarouselApp` in this case) and schedule a function using `Clock` as,

```
def on_start(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 1)
```

Then in the same class (`CarouselApp`) you should define `my_callback`:

```
def my_callback(self, nap):
    if condition_is_satisfied: # this is supposed to be your condition
        # control carousel
```

Comment: `AsyncImage` was a vestige from something I was doing before this. I meant to change it, sorry. The problem with using `Clock` for me is that the callback which controls the carousel is only supposed to fire once a certain external condition is satisfied. I think I need to develop other parts of the app first before this makes sense to me.

Comment: @Taira, what is that condition? is it a button pressed `Clock` is used to handle periodic events, so could you explain me more about how that condition is triggered?

Comment: It can be a button press but not necessarily. It's kind of hard to explain, but I think I'm starting to understand actually, and I think I remember having this same issue when I was learning tkinter. XD You can't control `CarouselApp` from the outside, because at the end of the day, kivy manifests itself as a big loop, and you can't interrupt that loop or kivy dies. Thus, the external part of my application has to be integrated into the `CarouselApp` class. I'll give that a go and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: This question has not been answered, I think the OP asked how to programmatically navigate slides and I would like to know the same thing. So how programmatically do i go to slide ```n``` via a method or function like ```def goto_slide(n): pass #?```?